# GROUP BY clause but with continuous(linear) values in a column

Tags: mysql, sql

table schema:

```
id(P)     date      price
```

want to use

```
"select date,price,count(price) from table group by price having count(price)>=5"
```

which results in group of all those rows(in this case 5 or more) that have same price and are not linear
For eg. if 1,2,3,4,5,6 are ids and 5,6,7,8,9,10 are dates with respective price as 2,3,2,2,2,2
,  the result would be as follow:

```
    date   price   count(*)
     5      2       5
```

but the problem is  i want only those rows that have same price for 5 or more continuous rows.So the above result only comes when price series is like

```
2,2,2,2,2,3
```

Thanks.

Comment: Where does date = 1 come from in your example?

Comment: does your query work when you dont group by `date` and select it ?

Comment: @CodeConfident in output date =1 is the min(date) which sql selects by default

Comment: @Badiparmagi i didn't get your question, i am applying group by on price instead of date

Comment: @vic - I asked because in your example data, 5 is the minimum date.

Comment: @CodeConfident my apologise to u, u r right

Comment: @vic - No need to apologise! Just trying to help! I recommend you edit that in your question to help future answers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `ORDER` the records by `date` and store the counts (for consecutive prices) into temporary variables, e.g.:

```
SELECT id, price, `date`, 
  IF(@previous = `price`, @count := @count + 1, @count := 1) AS `count`, 
  @previous := `price`
FROM test, (SELECT @previous := 0, @count := 1) a
ORDER BY date;
```

Once done, you can wrap this query into another `SELECT` and filter the records with counts more than 5, e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(b.price) FROM (
  SELECT id, price, `date`, 
    IF(@previous = `price`, @count := @count + 1, @count := 1) AS `count`, 
    @previous := `price`
  FROM test, (SELECT @previous := 0, @count := 1) a
  ORDER BY date
  ) b
  WHERE b.count >= 5;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6625b2/10/0)**.

Comment: it looks so much complex query in the sense of mine understandability,do you know any other way like some built in function of sql or if you could provide reference to your answer like how to use if(@previous='price') that would help alot.

Comment: It's complex only because of the `order by` clause. Group by does not go well with order by, so if you want to get 5 consecutive entries then yes, this is the way to go.

Comment: Don't you mean `ORDER BY date` instead of `ORDER BY price`?